# Installed SP2013 - unable to open Central Admin

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I just installed SP2013 on two servers and i'm not able to open up CA. No error messages and still nothing. Just a blank page. I've done IIS reset and even re-run the SP wizard. Any other steps I can do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to couple of things.

1. Disable the LoopBack check on the servers, [follow this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_foxhole/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way/)
2. try to open the site from local pc not from server.
3. Check the ULS Logs and Event Logs for more clue.
4. are you accessing site using server name and port number or FQDN? try with server name and port number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Waqas - i followed your steps and i nothing worked. As for the logs i can't pull the logs - how can i check the logs without central admin?

Comment: You will see the logs files on default location...in Hive Folder you will see the Logs folder(C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS)

Comment: How you accessing the site? server name and port number or?

Comment: ok i'll check the logs and let you know - i tried accessing the site via both IP and FQDN and same outcome.

Comment: Did you try to turn off the custom loggin fron Central admin web.config? check this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/disable-custom-error-mode-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Another good approach is enable the trace loggin on IIS...follow this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-central-admin-http-error-enable-failed-request-trace-logging/

Comment: Disabled the custom logging on central admin and no luck. I also did the tracing in IIS and it's not capturing anything since i don't really get an error msg. It's just a blank page

Comment: that is really bad? any firewall blocking? is your default web site is working...http://servername what u will get?

Comment: This is on my dev env. I'm going to try to re-install it and see what happens. I thought it could be something with permissions but all the accounts are setup correctly. I'll let you know once i have it re-installed.

Comment: So i've re-install SP2013, and still having the same blank page right after the install. I was able to change the settings on the trace logging in ISS and did get something. It says error 401 unauthorized access denied

Comment: it is not SharePoint issue, rather something else....do you know for which account it is saying 401? couple of things to check...Under which account Central admin app pool running? under which account SharePoint Timer services running....Both should be under Farm admin....Farm admin should have DBO on Config and Central admin dB